# MomentJS not a function problems with Nativescript

Tags: datetime, format, momentjs, nativescript

I'm following momentjs docs at http://momentjs.com/docs/ and I'm trying to get time difference from two moment time objects which are formatted to YYYY-MM-DD... I'm only gettin errors like "diff is not a function" "moment is not a function" and so on.

If someone has complete procedure how to implement momentjs correct way to use with diff and also duration functions, please let me know.

I have var moment = require('moment'); on Nativescript.

Comment: Post your entire code please (from the `require` to the `diff` call).

Comment: Got it working, my problem was that I did not format my string date correctly and those "not a function" errors came because my editor did not recognize correct functions.

Comment: Might want to answer your own question :) so this gets cleared from 'Unanswered'